# Delete lines that only contain 1 of each item

Tags: shell, awk

I have a rather interesting problem that I'm not sure how to approach. My file looks something like this:

```
GROUP1, 1 Tall.hat, 1 Bow.tie, 1 Shiny.shoe, 
GROUP2, 1350 Red.apple, 1 Black.pencil, 1 Blue.pen, 1 Green.pen, 1 Little.tree, 
GROUP30, 2 Green.bow, 4 Big.tree, 
GROUP170, 1 Yellow.banana, 2 Green.apple, 1 Blue.skirt, 1 Purple.top, 1 Silver.shoe,
GROUP6, 2 Tall.hat, 2 Bow.tie, 2 Shiny.shoe, 
GROUP7, 20 Red.apple, 20 Black.pencil, 20 Blue.pen, 20 Green.pen, 20 Little.tree,
```

Each line contains a group which contains items, e.g. GROUP1 contains 1 Tall.hat, 1 Bow.tie and 1 Shiny.shoe. Columns are separated by commas. I want to delete lines (or GROUPs) that only contain 1 of each item.

Desired output:

```
GROUP2, 1350 Red.apple, 1 Black.pencil, 1 Blue.pen, 1 Green.pen, 1 Little.tree, 
GROUP30, 2 Green.bow, 4 Big.tree, 
GROUP170, 1 Yellow.banana, 2 Green.apple, 1 Blue.skirt, 1 Purple.top, 1 Silver.shoe,
GROUP6, 2 Tall.hat, 2 Bow.tie, 2 Shiny.shoe, 
GROUP7, 20 Red.apple, 20 Black.pencil, 20 Blue.pen, 20 Green.pen, 20 Little.tree,
```

So GROUP1 has been deleted because it only contains 1 of each item. All other groups have at least one item with two copies or more.

Thoughts so far:

I need to ignore (but retain) column1, since that contains the group number. So start off with something like `awk -F "," 'NF>1'`. Then for each row, cycle through all the columns and record all the possible numbers found. E.g GROUP1=1; GROUP2=1350 or 1; GROUP30=2 or 4, GROUP170=1 or 2. If the only unique number found is 1, then delete that line.

Not sure how to actually implement this though...Any ideas would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using awk:

```
awk -F', *' '{ 
    split("", counts) # empty the counts array at the start of each line
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) { # loop through fields, starting from 2nd
        split($i, a, /[. ]/) # split each field into parts
        counts[a[3]] += a[1] # accumulate count for each type
        if (counts[a[3]] > 1) { print; next } # print and skip to next line
    }
}' file
```

`-F', *'` sets the field separator to a comma followed by any number of spaces. This makes things a bit easier, since the extra spaces are consumed and don't form part of each field `$2`, `$3` later on.

`counts` will contain keys like "apple", "pencil", "pen", etc. For each key, the value is the total number of occurrences.

If you keep separate counts for "Blue.pen" and "Green.pen", then just split on a single space `split($i, a, / /)`, rather than on spaces and dots. Now each field will only be split into two parts, so replace `a[3]` with `a[2]` in the subsequent lines.

`split`ting an empty string to clear the `counts` array is a workaround for non-GNU versions of awk, which can be replaced by `delete(counts)`.

Answer (score 0):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk -F", *" '{split($2,a," "); n=a[1]; for(i=3;i<NF;i++){ split($i,a," "); 
            if (a[1]!=n) { print; next} else {n=a[1]}} if(n!=1){ print } }' file
```

The output:

```
GROUP2, 1350 Red.apple, 1 Black.pencil, 1 Blue.pen, 1 Green.pen, 1 Little.tree, 
GROUP30, 2 Green.bow, 4 Big.tree, 
GROUP170, 1 Yellow.banana, 2 Green.apple, 1 Blue.skirt, 1 Purple.top, 1 Silver.shoe,
GROUP6, 2 Tall.hat, 2 Bow.tie, 2 Shiny.shoe, 
GROUP7, 20 Red.apple, 20 Black.pencil, 20 Blue.pen, 20 Green.pen, 20 Little.tree,
```

---

*Details*:

- `split($2,a," ")` - split an item by space so `a[1]` is filled with the number and `a[2]` contains the item name
- `n=a[1]` - capturing the number of the first item in each group
- `for(i=3;i<NF;i++)` - iterating through remaining items
- `if (a[1]!=n) { print; next}` - at the very first case when two consecutive item numbers are different - breaking the loop immediately(jumping to the `next` line) and printing the "proper" line
- `if(n!=1){ print }` - if all item numbers within the line do not differ (has the same value) and their value is not equal to `1` - print the line, otherwise - the line won't be printed

Comment: This is almost perfect! Except I want to keep lines which have the same item number. E.g. `GROUP5, 2 Green.bow, 2 Big.tree,` should be kept, not removed, whereas `GROUP6, 1 Green.bow, 1 Big.tree,` should be removed.

Comment: @gizmo, it's unclear from your explanation why some entry should be kept but some - removed, while they both have same numbers in their lines

Comment: Sorry, should have explained it better. I only want to remove lines that have ONE of each item. It's fine if they have 2 of each item, of 3 of each item, etc.

Comment: @gizmo, extend your input with all kinds of entries so I could idealize my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$ grep -E ' (1[0-9]|[2-9])' file
GROUP2, 1350 Red.apple, 1 Black.pencil, 1 Blue.pen, 1 Green.pen, 1 Little.tree,
GROUP30, 2 Green.bow, 4 Big.tree,
GROUP170, 1 Yellow.banana, 2 Green.apple, 1 Blue.skirt, 1 Purple.top, 1 Silver.shoe,
GROUP6, 2 Tall.hat, 2 Bow.tie, 2 Shiny.shoe,
GROUP7, 20 Red.apple, 20 Black.pencil, 20 Blue.pen, 20 Green.pen, 20 Little.tree,
```